# How persistent is IsolatedStorage on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am using the following code to save a list of about 100 objects to IsolatedStorage:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MyApp", theList);
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Loading is done in the following way:

```
theList = (List<Object>)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyApp"];
```

In the WP7 emulator, this code works: the list of data is correctly saved and loaded when restarting the app. However, when I restart the emulator the data is gone. Since I sadly don't own a Windows Phone 7, my question is: will this data be saved "forever" on a real phone? Or will the data vanish when the phone is turned off? I need to make sure that the list will not be deleted after a reboot of the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will persist through rebooting of the phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this also the best solution for my problem? Or is it better to - for example - serialize the list to a XML file?

Comment: I acutally store an XML file in isolated storage for my persistant data.

Comment: I explain why better to save Xml to a file, rather than to use `IsolatedStorageSettings`: when you retrieve `IsolatedStorageSettings` for the first time, OS perform load of ALL data stored here. If you have a lot of data in your list - it took a seconds to launch your app (you need some data from settings right after launch, right?). So, use `IsolatedStorageSettings` for SETTINGS, not a lists of dynamic data, etc.

Comment: You can still store your xml in isolated storage, and retrieve it asynchronously, without unneeded delays on the launch.  I do this in my apps, though I do not use the IsolatedStorageSettings, I manage my own file.